# Manually created CSS into LESS

Tags: css, less, decompiler

Is there a tool available for converting a manually created CSS file into a nested, well optimized LESS file?

Comment: There's this: http://leafo.net/lessphp/lessify/ - but it's incomplete to the point of mostly being useless. Just do it manually. Anyway, if you want to use LESS, you need understand it.

Comment: It seems sufficient for what I need, that is aggregation of nested classes - I'll do the rest manually. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Time to roll up your sleeves and re-create whatever css you have into .less files.

If you are building a framework, I highly suggest looking at [this](http://markdotto.com/bootstrap/), as it contains many variables and mixins that are helpful for .less files.

**Keep in mind** that while {less} is *awesome*, you should **not** use it for deployment. I suggest using your .less files for development only, and compiling them into minified .css files for deployment/production.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No. Do it yourself.

Long answer: Your CSS file should compile automatically with LESS. Rename .css to .less, then you can progressively improve your CSS file by adding LESS code. Yes it may be the slow way, but it is a great way to go.